# JS / jQuery - How together innerHTML of targeted element of a certain class and append /replace it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I want to get the text on click with a certain class but nothing works. I have a div with 2 p tags and I want to get both separate. Also, I want to append them. .append() appends but just keeps adding all targeted events. empty().append() gives me random results (on first click it works, on second I get half of the text etc). Ive tried most of what I could find on stack overflow but nothing helped. Any help would be great!

Ive tried:

1. `$(event.target).text();` //that gives me the text, but not both p elements separate
2. `$(this).hasClass('.video-title');` //only returns to me true/false
3. `var title= document.getElementsByClassName("video-title")[0].innerHTML;` //doesn't give me the current element.
4. `$('p.video-title').innerHTML;` //doesnt help either

*HTML*

```
<div class="video-container">
    <iframe id="vid_frame" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx?rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1" width="900" height="450"></iframe>
    <div id="video-info"></div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4 video-col">
    <div class="video-wrapper" onClick="attachSrc('yyy', event)">
        <img src="assets/images/thumbnail/yourHeart_official.jpg" width="260" height="160">
        <div class="overlay">
            <p class="video-title">title 1</p>
            <p class="video-author">author 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 video-col">
    <div class="video-wrapper" onClick="attachSrc('xxx', event)">
        <img src="assets/images/thumbnail/yourHeart_karaoke.jpg" width="260" height="160">
        <div class="overlay">
            <p class="video-title">title 2</p>
            <p class="video-author">author 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
   function attachSrc(id, event) {
      var text =  $(event.target).text();
      $('#video-info').append(text);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery, I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler and use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers.

Here in example I have attached event with wrapper element and DOM traversal method to traverse and target desired element.

And to persists arbitrary data use `data-*` prefixed custom attribute which can be fetched using `.data(key)`

```
<div class="video-wrapper" data-id="yyy">
```

*Script*

```
$('.video-col').on('click', '.video-wrapper', function() {
  var elem = $('#video-info').empty();
  var title = $(this).find('.video-title').text();
  elem.append(title);
  console.log(title);

  var author= $(this).find('.video-author').text();
  elem.append(author);
  console.log(author);

  console.log($(this).data('id'));// To fetch custom data associated with element
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.video-col').on('click', '.video-wrapper', function() {
    console.clear();
    var elem = $('#video-info').empty();
    var title = $(this).find('.video-title').text();
    elem.append(title);
    console.log(title);

    var author = $(this).find('.video-author').text();
    elem.append(author);
    console.log(author);

    console.log($(this).data('id')); // To fetch custom data associated with element
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container">

  <div id="video-info"></div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4 video-col">
  <div class="video-wrapper" data-id="yyy">
    <img src="assets/images/thumbnail/yourHeart_official.jpg" width="260" height="160">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p class="video-title">title 1</p>
      <p class="video-author">author 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 video-col">
  <div class="video-wrapper" data-id="xxx">
    <img src="assets/images/thumbnail/yourHeart_karaoke.jpg" width="260" height="160">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p class="video-title">title 2</p>
      <p class="video-author">author 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to call my function from my html, because Im also passing an id for my iframe (which i need for something unrelated to my question). if I have my function (as posted) and pass in: var elem = $('#video-info').empty();
  elem.append($(this).find('.video-title').text());
  elem.append($(this).find('.video-author').text()); nothing happens at all

Comment: Is `yyyy` and `xxxx` then? then I have updated answer for that

Comment: yes yyy and xxx is the id but I can't just fetch it. Its actually the number for the src of the iframe and as its nowhere included (i display images, on click the matching youtube video is played)- thats why I have to actually call my function from my html and actively passing in the correct number

Comment: @julicode, Notice `<div class="video-wrapper" data-id="yyy">` and `console.log($(this).data('id'));` also see the code snippet

Comment: sorry, I missed one part of your answer. Thanks it works now :) Just one more thing- I need to get both p elements separate as I want to add styling to both elements (a different one for title as for author) how can I do that using your solution?

Comment: sorry, I meant more how to add class using your code- I tried to do this: var title = $(this).find('.video-title').text().addClass('title'); but im getting an error

Comment: nevermind, I didn't use addClass and just added this:   title1='<p class="title">'+title+'</p>';